# Passing Azure token (JWT) with API calls on SPA

Tags: azure, symfony, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I have a SPA that calls a PHP backend (based on Symfony currently for proof of concept).

Authentication for this application is based upon an Azure Active Directory, and all azure users are matched against the local application user table on their email address and OID - if not registered locally then a local account is created for them with basic privileges.

For authentication, a call to the backend which then redirects to Azure to authenticate, and then the access token is returned. Instead of re-inventing my own auth token system in the backend, can I just get the SPA to pass the Azure access token in the API calls and validate it on the backend, letting the SPA deal with refreshing the token as and when required?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes - in this partial SPA model you will typically need to store a refresh token in an http only secure cookie. When the web UI calls an API and gets a 401 expired response it will need to call the back end to refresh the token.

Comment: Actually in the Implicit Flow it is a good idea to store the token neither in local storage nor in a cookie due to replay attacks. Just keep it in memory.